# Sleep .NET Task, Wake on CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have code that must poll an external resource periodically.  Simplified, it looks like:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!cancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fairly complex polling logic here.");

            // Finishes sleeping before checking for cancellation request
            Thread.Sleep(10000); 
        }
    },
    cancellationSource.Token);
```

How can I code the 10 second delay in such a manner that it will be interrupted if cancellationSource.Cancel() is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a Monitor with a timeout of 10 seconds. You can wake the sleeping thread up with the Pulse method of the Monitor class

Thread 1:

```
Monitor.Wait(monitor, 10000);
```

Thread 2:

```
Monitor.Pulse(monitor);
```

Or you could look at [ManualResetEvent.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.waitone.aspx). Block the thread with a 10 second timeout. To unblock, signal an event.

EDIT:

The CancellationToken has a .WaitHandle property:

> Gets a WaitHandle that is signaled when the token is canceled.

You can wait on that handle to be signaled, with a timeout of 10 seconds?

Comment: That would probably work, but it seems ... wrong... to require a second thread to pulse the first one, just to get an interruptable sleep.

Comment: But if the thread is asleep I don't see how it can be woken, unless from another thread. An ugly way would be to make it more granular. A loop to do smaller sleeps, that checks on the cancel boolean. Probs not ideal from a CPU perspective.

Comment: Conceptually the thread scheduler could interrupt the call to whatever is delaying/waiting if the cancellation token is canceled.  Not sure whether that can be done practically.

Comment: Perfect!  That worked.  `cancellationSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);`